# How to force Jetty to redownload a modules external libs after Jetty home upgrade

Tags: jetty-9

I've split up my Jetty installation from my configuration by using the ["Jetty Base and Jetty Home"](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.6.v20170531/startup-base-and-home.html) mechanism.

This made it very easy to upgrade Jetty 9.4.3 to 9.4.6 by just referencing to the new Jetty home directory.

In my Jetty base directory I have activated the `cdi module`, which had downloaded various lib files under `{$jetty.base}/lib/cdi`.

Although Jetty 9.4.6 has new versions of the weld framework referenced in its module description, those libs in my Jetty base directory did not get updated automatically. What is the recommended way to update these libs?

Deactivating the module, deleting the libs and reactivating it feels a little bit odd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `--create-files` to your `start.jar` command line once.

If the module is defined properly (sometimes it isn't. if so, that's a bug), only the specific jar files needed are referenced, not the old ones.

Comment: A hint in the documentation would be very handy. Maybe in the "Upgrading Jetty" chapter?! Thanks for your help Joakim